# IE8 - iframe with flash inside draggable div - poor redraw

Tags: jquery, css, flash, internet-explorer-8, draggable

I have a draggable popup window that has a title bar and an iframe in its content area. The iframe has a flash object embedded in it. It works great in all browser except for IE8 (IE7 and IE9 work fine). IE8 has a bad drawing problem when the window is being moved. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6cvG/3/

Open the example in IE8, or if you're using IE9, hit F12 for developer tools, then select Browser Mode: IE8 using IE8 Standards.

Drag the window around quickly and you'll see a very bad redraw of the iframe. If you remove the iframe and enter a paragraph, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding WMODE=OPAQUE to your object/embed of your Flash movie may help. It prevents Flash from trying to figure out whether it needs to deal with background opacity issues.

Comment: Ah! I should have known! Thank you.